# How to start Swing timer?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, timer, actionlistener

Right now, the object moves a certain increment each time I manually click a button, but its actually suppose to move on its own across the screen on its own once the button is clicked. I tried calling timer.start(); various times in my code. As well as, setting up an 'if' statement in the actionPerformed method that checks for a button being pressed and then calls timer.start() as a result. But, it didn't get the object to move on its own.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Am I not writing the code right? Or is does this problem have something to do with java swing timer.

PS. I am new to java,

And this is part of my code :

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if (e.getSource() == rightBtn) {    
        objXpos += objMoveIncrement;
        direction.equals("Right");

    }
    if (e.getSource() == leftBtn) {
        direction.equals("Left");
        objXpos -= objMoveIncrement;
    }

    repaint();
```

}
}
**edit 
the timer is suppose to start once a button is clicked, and the timer is what allows the object to move across the screen

Comment: Perhaps add a bit more of your code? What have you tried with the timer?

Answer (score 1):

> this problem have something to do with java swing timer.

No.

> Am I not writing the code right?

That would be the problem.

> the timer is suppose to start once a button is clicked

And how does the Timer stop? What happens if you click "right" and then "down"?

Without knowing the exact requirements it is hard to give an exact solution.

So I would suggest that one solution is to just start the Timer when your program starts.

Then in the ActionListener for each button, you change the direction.

Then when the ActionListner for the Timer is invoked, you simply move the object based on the current direction and then repaint the object.

Generally you would use `Key Bindings` for something like this. So when you press a key you start the Timer and when you release the key you stop the Timer. Check out the `Motion With Key Bindings` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example of this approach.